# How to initialize a very long array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization, segmentation-fault

I am just trying to initialize a huge array. My code is given below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    while (T--) 
    {
        int d;
        cin >> d;
        int arr[d + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= d; i++)
            arr[i] = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I input

```
1 502334160
```

then I got error `Runtime Error - SIGSEGV`.

I want to know how to initialize this type of array.

Comment: Don't use variable length arrays in C++. Either use `vector`, or allocate the memory yourself with `new`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: ***I want to know how to initialize this type of array*** VLAs (which are not part of standard c++) are usually limited to the stack size which is likely only a few MB by default. To solve this use `std::vector` which is part of standard `c++` and does not have this memory limitation.

Answer (score 1):

The array may be too big to fit in your program's stack address space. If you allocate the array on the heap you should be fine.

`int* arr = new int[d + 1];`

But remember that this will require you to [`delete[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/) the array. A better solution would be to use [`std::vector<int>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) and [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) it to `d + 1` elements.

Answer (score 0):

First: Variable length arrays (VLA) are illegal in C++. It might be an extension (as it is in gcc), but it won't build on all compilers.

Second: You can initialize an array with brace initialization. If you don't specify all elements, the others will get default value of 0 (in case of `int`). So:

```
int arr[SIZE] {} //specify 0 elements -> all initialized to value 0
```

Third thing: you allocate your array on stack, so when you create an array of length `1502334160` than it's stack overflow. This amount of ints (assuming 4 bytes each) is almost 6GB of memory while stack is usually 1-2MB.